# How to retain cookies across multiple post requests in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, cookies, meteor, npm, httprequest

I want to re-use cookie got from the response of one post request in further post requests.In the following server-side code I'm getting the cookie as JSON Object

```
 Meteor.methods({
   'login':function(){
      var cookieData = "";
      var loginUrl = "http://somesite.com/login.page";
      var loginData = {params:{username:"myUserName",password:"mySeceret"},headers:{"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"}};
      var homePage = HTTP.post(loginUrl,loginData);
      var cookieData = homePage.headers["set-cookie"];
      var secondPageUrl = "http://somesite.com/scond.page"
      var postData  = {params:{param1:"value1",param2:"value2"},headers:{Cookie:cookieData,"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"}};
      var secondResponse = HTTP.post(secondPageUrl,postData);
    }
   })
```

I'm getting the **secondResponse.statusCode** as 302 instead of 200.
The variable **cookieData** is a JSON object, Now how to use the content of **cookieData** in further post requests ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the cookieData is a JSON object, you might have to convert it into a string when you pass it into the Cookie property of the second request's header. Try that.